# ASP.NET Populate dropdown based on other dropdown selected option AJAX

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

Maybe you would help me. Cause I got stuck. I am not that good in jquery/ajax. SO the problem is that Ajax does not get the answer from server. It should the json array. It says: Failed to load resource: *the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)*.

What I want to do is basically populate drodon based on selected option of another.

**c#:**

```
protected String ajax_test(String value)
    {

        DropDownForTime.Items.Clear();
        List<String> timesarray = new List<String>();
        String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id from Movies WHERE Name='"+value+"'", con);
            con.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.Read())
            {
                /*int a = int.Parse(reader[0].ToString());
                selectTimes(a);*/

                int movieid = int.Parse(reader[0].ToString());

                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT Time from Time WHERE MovieID = '"+movieid+"'", con);
                SqlDataReader reader2 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader2.Read())
                {
                    timesarray.Add(reader[0].ToString());
                }
            }

            var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            String json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(timesarray);

            return json;
        }
    }


<div class="form-group">
                <asp:Label ID="LabelForMovie" runat="server" Text="Select a movie"></asp:Label>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownForMovie" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:DropDownList>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <asp:Label ID="LabelForTime" runat="server" Text="Choose time"></asp:Label>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownForTime" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
```

**jquery/ajax:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#DropDownForMovie").change(function () {

                var s = $("#DropDownForMovie").find(":selected").text();
                var n = $("#DropDownForTime");

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "UserHome.aspx/ajax_test",
                    data: { value: s },
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (e) {
                        var obj = e.parseJSON();

                        $.each(obj, function (index, value) {
                            n.append("<option>" + value.text() + "</option>");
                        });
                    }
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Probably there are not only one mistake but more. Maybe some of you will show the correct way.

P.S I know I can make the same using c# AutoPostBack and SelectedItemsIndexOnChange, but I want to use ajax for learning reasons.

*Thank you.*

Comment: This seems like a server side error. Your ajax code seems valid. Run a debugger on ajax_text method

Comment: Add the [WebMethod] attribute to your ajax_test method.

Comment: Still says Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) : //

Comment: Where should I look for problem here?

Answer (score 0):

i dont think u should use ajax for control dropdownlist because returned values aren't contained in viewstate. therefore, after postback to sẻrver, errors oftens cause. u use autopostback and updatepanel with dropdownlist

Comment: What do you mean aren't contained in viewstate? I am using. var n = $("#DropDownForTime"); And then populate by var obj = e.parseJSON();

                        $.each(obj, function (index, value) {
                            n.append("<option>" + value.text() + "</option>");
                        }); Hm ? ;/

Comment: because server control in asp will generate new id therefore u want to use jquery, u have to $('<%#eval("dropdownfortime")%>. if u dont use viewstatte, and want to get value, u hace to use request.form